# @RestController @Autowired Null

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

При попытке запроса метода, выдаёт NullPointerException конкретно по этому контроллеру. Есть похожие, и они абсолютно идентичные, в плане аннотаций и тд контроллеры. Пробовал разные аннотации на все из перечисленных классов. И конечно же на всех зависимостях есть нужные аннотации.

**Exception**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.honeym.api.repository.PositionRepository.save(Object)" because "this.positionRepository" is null
    at org.honeym.api.controller.PositionController.createPosition(PositionController.java:52) ~[main/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPut(FrameworkServlet.java:920) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:684) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:111) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.honeym.api.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthTokenFilter.java:51) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.honeym.api.security.jwt.AuthTokenFilter.doFilterInternal(AuthTokenFilter.java:51) ~[main/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:112) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183) ~[spring-security-web-5.7.1.jar:5.7.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.20.jar:5.3.20]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.63.jar:9.0.63]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

**PositionController**

```
package org.honeym.api.controller;

import org.honeym.api.exception.PositionException;
import org.honeym.api.model.EChangeObjects;
import org.honeym.api.model.EChangeResults;
import org.honeym.api.model.Position;
import org.honeym.api.payload.request.CreatePositionRequest;
import org.honeym.api.payload.response.ESimpleResponse;
import org.honeym.api.payload.response.SimpleResponse;
import org.honeym.api.repository.PositionRepository;
import org.honeym.api.service.LogService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;


@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v1/positions")
public class PositionController {

    @Autowired
    private PositionRepository positionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LogService logService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/create", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('OWNER')")
    private ResponseEntity<?> createPosition(
            @RequestHeader(value = "X-Forwarded-For") String ip,
            @RequestHeader(value = "User-Agent") String userAgent,
            @RequestHeader(value = "Referer") String referer,
            @Valid @RequestBody CreatePositionRequest request
    ) {
        Position position = new Position(
                request.getName(),
                null,
                request.getType()
        );

        if(request.getControlledPositionId() != null) {
            position.setControlledPosition(
                    positionRepository.findById(
                            request.getControlledPositionId()).orElseThrow(() -> new PositionException("Position not found")
                    )
            );
        }

        positionRepository.save(position);

        logService.createChangeLogList(
                EChangeObjects.POSITION,
                EChangeResults.CREATED,
                ip,
                userAgent,
                referer,
                position
        );

        return ResponseEntity.ok(new SimpleResponse(ESimpleResponse.SUCCESS));
    }
}
```

**PositionRepository**

```
package org.honeym.api.repository;

import org.honeym.api.model.Position;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface PositionRepository extends MongoRepository<Position, String> {

}
```

**LogService**

```
package org.honeym.api.service;

import org.honeym.api.model.*;
import org.honeym.api.repository.ChangeLogRepository;
import org.honeym.api.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@Service
@Component
public class LogService {
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ChangeLogRepository changeLogRepository;

    public void createChangeLogList(
            EChangeObjects changeObjects,
            EChangeResults changeResults,
            String ip,
            String userAgent,
            String referer,
            Object object
    ) {
        changeLogRepository.save(new ChangeLog(
                ip,
                userAgent,
                referer,
                changeObjects,
                changeResults,
                object
                ));
    }

    public List<UserLog> createUserLogList(
            EActions action,
            EActionResults result,
            String ip,
            String userAgent,
            String referer,
            String apiEndPoint,
            List<UserLog> userLogList
    ) {
        UserLog userLog = new UserLog(
                ip,
                userAgent,
                referer,
                apiEndPoint,
                action,
                result
        );
        if(userLogList == null) {
            List<UserLog> newUserLogList = new ArrayList<>();
            newUserLogList.add(userLog);
            return newUserLogList;
        } else {
            userLogList.add(userLog);
            return userLogList;
        }
    }
}
```

**application.properties**

```
logging.level.root=DEBUG

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG

server.address=
server.port=
server.ssl.enabled=
server.ssl.key-store=
server.ssl.key-store-password=
server.ssl.key-store-type=
server.ssl.key-alias=

springdoc.swagger-ui.path=

spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database=
spring.data.mongodb.database=
spring.data.mongodb.host=
spring.data.mongodb.username=
spring.data.mongodb.password=
spring.data.mongodb.port=

spring.mail.protocol=
spring.mail.host=
spring.mail.port=
spring.mail.username=
spring.mail.password=
spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.enable=
spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.ssl.trust=
spring.mail.properties.mail.debug=

spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size=
spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size=
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=true

honey.app.jwtSecret =
honey.app.jwtExpirationHours =
honey.app.jwtRefreshExpirationHours =
honey.app.jwtRefreshRememberExpirationHours =
```

**Folder structure**
[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась сама собой, после того как я пересоздал класс PositionController, скопировав оболочку класса из предыдущего заведомо рабочего контроллера, и поместив туда так же скопированную логику из не рабочего PositionController.

Comment: Что-то тут нечисто. Спринг завалился бы при старте, если бы не смог найти зависимость, помеченную `@Autowired`. Я думаю, что в изначальной версии класса зависимость не была помечена `@Autowired`. Потом ты поставил `@Autowired`, но либо не перекомпилировал, либо не перестартовал и получил этот странный стэктрэйс. Потом пересоздал класс, но в этот раз и аннотация, и компиляция и рестарт были выполнены в правильном порядке и без пропусков, поэтому всё заработало.

Comment: Возможно, но в дебаг логах я видел чётко что он создавал bean, так что мне самому непонятно было. У меня в идеи стоит ремоут деплой, поэтому мне приходится каждый раз билдить его, и отправлять на сервер, а там уже запускать. Я сначала подумал что в этом проблема, отрубал rsync и удалял все на сервер, и заново деплоил, и другие манипуляции, но бестолку. До этого ещё удалял полность файл класса, скопировав его перед этим, и заново создавал из буфера. Но помогло именно скопировать другой рабочий контроллер.

Comment: А запущенный сервис останавливал перед всеми манипуляциями? Если нет, то обновлённый сервис мог стартовать, создавать бины, а потом падать, потому что порт занят. А старый сервис продолжал работать. Так что на счёт "в изначальной версии класса зависимость не была помечена @Autowired" - если это верно, то я на 99.9% уверен и во всём остальном.

Comment: "в дебаг логах я видел чётко что он создавал bean" - создание бина репозитория произошло бы в любом случае. А вот вставка его в контроллер только если поле помечено `@Autowired`

Comment: Останавливал, но ты имеешь в виду, что новый сервер мог запускаться на другом порту? Если так, то у меня там 443 установлен в настройках, и он не смог бы запуститься. Поэтому у меня уже ритуал: остановил, собрал, деплойнул. Я спецом функционал менял, да бы убедиться в том, что всё ок, и дебаггер бы по коду не работал. Так что я уверен, в том что его останавливал.